# Extract mysql dump when docker container is building

Tags: mysql, docker

I try to extract mysql dump when docker container is building but I got an empty table. This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:5.7

ARG MYSQL_DATABASE
ARG MYSQL_USER
ARG MYSQL_PASSWORD
ARG MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

# Create Database
RUN mkdir /usr/sql
RUN chmod 644 /usr/sql

COPY dump.sql /usr/sql/dump.sql
COPY mysql.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf

#Create database
RUN /etc/init.d/mysql start && \
    sleep 5 && \
    mysql -u root -p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} -e "CREATE DATABASE ${MYSQL_DATABASE}" && \
    mysql -u root -p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} -e "CREATE USER '${MYSQL_USER}'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_PASSWORD}'" && \
    mysql -u root -p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO '${MYSQL_USER}'@'localhost';" && \
    mysql -u root -p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES" && \
    mysql -u root -p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} ${MYSQL_DATABASE} <  /usr/sql/dump.sql
```

When container is ready I have an empty database (without tables and data)

Comment: Can you try cleanly stopping the mysql server?